# Check object type and convert to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two methods:

```
async def broadcast(self, message: WebSocketMessage):
    for web_socket in self._websockets:
        await web_socket.send(json.dumps(message.as_dict()))

async def broadcast_all(self, messages: List[WebSocketMessage]):
    dumped_messages = json.dumps([msg.as_dict() for msg in messages])
    for web_socket in self._websockets:
        await web_socket.send(dumped_messages)
```

I want to have just one method that can take as a parameter `WebSocketMessage` or `List[WebSocketMessage]`. If it's not a `List` than cast it to list and do the same thing as `broadcast_all` did.

What is the best way to do this kind of preprocessing?

That's what I did:

```
async def broadcast_all(self, messages: object):
    if not isinstance(messages, list):
        messages = list(messages)
    dumped_messages = json.dumps([msg.as_dict() for msg in messages])
    for web_socket in self._websockets:
        await web_socket.send(dumped_messages)
```

Is it good way to do this?

Comment: Why not make `messages: list` and get the caller to wrap as needed? Why is it sometimes not a list?

Comment: ...what? Of course programmers need to think about what types things are.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, question updated

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but [messages] does not do what you think it does. That statement will return a list containing whatever object is stored in messages as it's first element.

```
tup = (1,2,3)
new = [tup]
# the result of this will be [(1,2,3)]
```

Instead, you should just use the builtin list() to typecast.

```
messages = list(messages)
```